# Problems getting SvnKit to work on 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, 64-bit, svnkit

I'm having a problem getting SvnKit working on 64 bit Windows 7. I open a shell and type jsvn and i get...

The system cannot find the path specified.

It doesn't say what path. Its not the launcher script as I've checked all the paths. It must be within one of the svnkit jars or a dependent jar.

This is the 1.3.4.6888 standalone version. My installed JRE is 1.6.0_22.

Has anyone seen this problem on 64 bit Windows 7?

Edited to show launcher script:

It seems that java isn't even getting called from the jsvn.bat file.

Here is the contents of that file...

```
set DEFAULT_SVNKIT_HOME=%~dp0

if "%SVNKIT_HOME%"=="" set SVNKIT_HOME=%DEFAULT_SVNKIT_HOME%

set SVNKIT_CLASSPATH="%SVNKIT_HOME%svnkit.jar";"%SVNKIT_HOME%svnkit-cli.jar";"%SVNKIT_HOME%trilead.jar";"%SVNKIT_HOME%jna.jar";"%SVNKIT_HOME%sqljet.1.0.3.jar";"%SVNKIT_HOME%antlr-runtime-3.1.3.jar"
set SVNKIT_MAINCLASS=org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.svn.SVN
set SVNKIT_OPTIONS=-Djava.util.logging.config.file="%SVNKIT_HOME%logging.properties"

"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" %SVNKIT_OPTIONS% -cp %SVNKIT_CLASSPATH% %SVNKIT_MAINCLASS% %*
```

So somewhere a bad path exists and the script never invokes the java command. If I turn on echo and observe the console output and then enter the java command by hand it works.

I'm stumped.

Comment: You could use Process Monitor from SysInternals to see what it isn't finding.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I checked it out and it seems java is never getting invoked so the problem is indeed in the launcher script but I cannot see the problem.

Comment: Do you have to use the 64 bit version of svnkit for some reason? My team and I have had problems with the 64 bit version. After switching to 32 bit things have gone well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working finally. The problem was with the JAVA_HOME variable being set incorrectly for the shell session. I have several shell environments for different tasks and the wrong one was being used. Yup. Human error!